# Does IronRuby have an issue with each_for_index?

Tags: ironruby

I'm working on some stuff in IronRuby, but I've run into a bit of a snag.  This chunk of code:

```
def func
    b = @b
    b.each_with_index do |element, index|
        <some stuff in here>
    end
end
```

gives the following error:

```
./myfile.rb:<line number>:in 'func': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from IronRuby.Libraries:0:in '<EachWithIndex>b__9'
    from IronRuby.Libraries:0:in 'each'
    from IronRuby.Libraries:0:in 'Each'
    from ./myfile.rb:<line number>:in 'each_with_index'
    from ./myfile.rb:<line number>:in 'func'
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?  I'm using IronRuby 1.0 (the .NET 2.0 version).  It's probably something ridiculously obvious, but I just haven't been able to find the answer.

As a note:  I've thrown a bunch of puts statements in there, and b is definitely an Array, so it's not like I'm trying to do this on something it shouldn't work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out, IronRuby targets Ruby 1.8.6, and apparently each_for_index didn't return an enumerator in 1.8.6.  I've changed it to:

```
require 'enumerator'

b.enum_for(:each_with_index) do |element, index|
```

and it seems to work fine.